# Parents Visa for US

Tags: visas, tourist-visas

I am a F1 student in US. I am graduating in May and planning to call my parents for my convocation. I have some questions regarding the visa that they should apply for coming to US for 20 days:-

> 1. Is the visa that I should apply should be B1/B2? Since this is equivalent to tourism purpose.
> 2. Can I fill DS-160 form of my parents on their behalf?
> 3. Will the separate DS-160 form need to be filled for my mother and father or it can be done together?
> 4. Can the interview be taken in Hindi instead of English? Where can I specify that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the visa that I should apply should be B1/B2? Since this is
>   equivalent to tourism purpose.

Yes.

> Can I fill DS-160 form of my parents on their behalf?

Yes. Please see [the official FAQ](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/forms/ds-160-online-nonimmigrant-visa-application/ds-160-faqs.html), question "*Can a third party complete the form on my behalf?*"

> Will the separate DS-160 form need to be filled for my mother and
>   father or it can be done together?

Each applicant needs a separate form, but the system can automatically reuse and fill up some of the information. Please see the question "*I am traveling with my family or as part of a group. Can I create a family or group application?*" in the FAQ above. Note that the applications are still evaluated separately, and it is theoretically possible for one parent to qualify for the visa, while another parent wouldn't qualify.

> Can the interview be taken in Hindi instead of English? Where can I
>   specify that?

From my limited experience, the US nonimmigrant visa interviews seem to be typically conducted in the native language of the country/area where the embassy is located. Thus this is likely the case in India as well.